# vCenter cannot join Active Directory saying "Error: Domain controllers not found for domain."

Tags: active-directory, vsphere, domaincontroller, vcenter

Hi I got stuck in setting up vCenter to connect Active Directory.

It says "Error: Domain controllers not found for domain.", though I can lookup the SRV record of the domain (_ldap._tcp.domain.domain) by dig command.

So I dumped DNS packets on the vCenter machine, then I found that after successfully looking up the SRV record of "_ldap._tcp.domain.domain", vCenter tries to look up the SRV record of "_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.domain" for some reason, and failed.

Do you know how to solve this problem??

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 0):

If your domain is in fact domain.domain then you should to check DNS zone config in DNS server that operates your AD domain.

Query "_ldap._tcp.{full domain name}" will return LDAP servers.
Query "_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.{full domain name}" should return AD domain controller servers that holds your domain. I've check in my domain - that query works fine and returns AD DC servers addresses. So at first you should to check running nslookup:

> set type=srv
>
> _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.domain

And it should to return list of domain controllers.